# SQL: A mildly-complex query to optimize

Tags: sql, database, query-optimization

Okay, we have a database, with a not-so-good tables-columns layout, for a small news agency functioning online. Changing the layout is, currently, not possible; so, I'm focused on the queries.

Webpage requires a list of "guest" authors. Each list item should contain:

- Author's image (Authors)
- Author's name (Authors)
- Title of the last article he/she wrote (News)
- URI of that article (News)

In parentheses are the table names that info is stored in.

In "Authors" (40+ records), relevant columns are:

- Image
- Name
- Type (we'll look for the value "Guest" here)
- ASCII (stores the "Name" value but without non-English characters and spaces)

The "News" (28k+ records) table is, basically, a pool where all the news and articles are pouring in. Columns of interest would be:

- Id (primary key: the higher, the more recent)
- Category
- Title
- URI

Now, "Category" has a whole bunch of values; however, if the particular record is an article, this column holds the "ASCII" of "Authors" (rather than its "Id", sadly).

There was a PHP code, "while"ing queries for each author. I wanted to replace that when I saw it. So, I thought, "Hmm... How to fetch these in one go?" and came up with this:

```sql
-- Aliases are prefixed with 't' for tables and 'c' for columns.
SELECT
  tAu.Image, tAu.Name, tNw.Title, tNw.URI
FROM ( -- tAu & tNw

    SELECT * FROM ( -- tRc & Authors

        SELECT
          MAX(Id) cId, Category cCt -- Max Id for most recent
        FROM
          News
        GROUP BY
          cCt

    ) tRc -- table of categories with their most recent id's
    INNER JOIN
      Authors
    ON
      tRc.cCt = Authors.ASCII
    WHERE
      Authors.Type = 'Guest'

) tAu -- table of authors with their most recent id's
INNER JOIN
  News tNw
ON
  tAu.cId = tNw.Id -- merging authors with their latest article info
```

Currently, this query takes around 0.0364 seconds. May not be that bad; but, I am curious if this can be made any better (as this query SELECTs twice from News).

Comment: Which DBMS, and how are these tables indexed?

Comment: Performance of queries is mostly dependent on indicies. Also it is often different from DBMS to DBMS on how to make the DBMS use the right index if not doing it right on its own. What indicies are on the table and if your DBMS allows a explain plan (I think most databases have that feature), what indicies are used in this query? Are there indicies on what you use in the where and on clause?

Comment: You shouldn't need to prefix aliases with type - I don't think it's possible, in _any_ RDBMS, to provide one for the other.  **Typed** Hungarian notation (and prefixing/suffixing) are generally frowned upon.  Your names also aren't terribly long - just use the table names.

Comment: Oh, it's MySQL 5.1.63-cll.

Apparently, only the primary keys are indexed. Not familiar with the best practices so I'm not sure which types of columns are best indexed.

Comment: Prefixing was my attempt to make the aliases more uhm... understandable; though, it seems, they have complicated the query further :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is faster or not, but cleaned up your query a bit, which may help the optimizer:

```
SELECT
  Authors.Image,
  Authors.Name,
  News.Title,
  News.URI

FROM (
    SELECT
      MAX(Id) TopNewsId,
      Category
    FROM News
    GROUP BY Category
) TopNewsPerCats

INNER JOIN News     ON News.Id       = TopNewsPerCats.TopNewsId

INNER JOIN Authors  ON Authors.ASCII = TopNewsPerCats.Category
                   AND Authors.Type  = 'Guest'
```

`News` table should have an index starting with `( Category, Id)` to speed up the internal `SELECT GROUP BY`.

Comment: Wow, it sure is more readable, thanks! I wasn't sure about indexing the Category column. They have around 40 distinct values and each no longer than two words. How long would it lock the table to index those?